# Laravel - Filtering a Model by Condition between "a Field and Its Relationship Model Field"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, subquery

I have these two models with one to one relationship.

"products"

- id
- name
- minimum_required

"product_data"

- id
- product_id
- price
- oh_hand

> I want to get the count of product_data where its on_hand is less than
> its related product's minimum_required.

I've tried subqueries and I still can't figure it out. The query I want may looks something like this.

```
$low_products_count = ProductDetail::where('on_hand', '<', Product::select('minimum_required')->count();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can join the tables then use 'whereColumn':

```
 $low_products_count =Product::join('product_data','product_data.product_id','=',
    'products.id')->whereColumn('product_data.on_hand','<','products.minimum_required')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not experienced with the eloquent So here, I share my knowledge with the query builder.

You can do like this->

```
$low_products_count=DB::table('products')
                    ->join('product_data','product_data.product_id','=',
                     'product.id')
->where('product_data.on_hand','<','products.minimum_required')->get();
```

You can use this concept.